# How to implement LocalStorage?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

How to implement LocalStorage in the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/k7aw2Lzr/29/) below? Values should be reset when the page is refreshed.
I already forced to work localstorage for several blocks (# delivery-time, # delivery-now). I can not figure out how to make other blocks work with localstorage. Please, check jsfiddle for the entire code.

```
$("#delivery-now").on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$('#delivery-now').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', true);
    $("#delivery-time").removeClass('active');
        localStorage.setItem("activeButton", $(".active").attr("id"));
  }
});
$("#delivery-time").on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$('#delivery-time').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', true);
    $("#delivery-now").removeClass('active');
        localStorage.setItem("activeButton", $(".active").attr("id"));
  }
});
var activeId = localStorage.getItem("activeButton");
if (activeId) {
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $("#" + activeId).addClass("active"); 
}
```

Comment: your question isn't clear. Kindly, provide some further explanations.

Comment: Now LocalStorage works for #delivery-now and #delivery-time.  #delivery-text, #date, #hours and other blocks must store values on page reload (https://jsfiddle.net/k7aw2Lzr/29/).

Comment: Can you share your HTML

Comment: You can find entire code here: https://jsfiddle.net/k7aw2Lzr/29/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
var activeId = localStorage.getItem("activeButton");
if (activeId) {
  //$(".active").removeClass("active");
  //$("#" + activeId).addClass("active"); 
  $("#" + activeId).click();
}
```